# Dataset Select Statement? In Asp.net

Tags: asp.net

In web application, I fetch the data from back end and the data is now availbale in dataset. I have 5 columns in that dataset, but i need only one column, so how can i get only one column out of 5 columns. I use dataview but it is not getting.

```
               DataView dv = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
               dv.RowFilter= "empid";
```

but i am not getting. can you helpme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of dataview you can create another table which has only required columns which  you need

```
DataView view = new DataView(ds.tables[0]);
DataTable newTable = view.ToTable(tabblename, false, params string[] columnNames
```

);//Add name of required

You can get full example from the below link

[Click](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h2b6ehaa.aspx)

or

You can remove extra columns

```
ds.Tables[string].Columns.Remove(string)
```

to remove individual columns which you feel are extra one.

Don't forget to ds.AcceptChanges() after deleting rows or they will still be in the dataset.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `dv.AutoGenerateMembers` to `false` then create on column inside your`DataView` (using designer approach) that matches the names of that column you want to show on the `DataView`

Comment: Hi,Rami i not get dv.autogenratemember

Comment: Well yes, its my bad, I thought its a `gridView`